# Faking GetAsync call from test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing

```
public Fixture()
{
      _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()    
         .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .ConfigureServices(services =>
           {
              services.AddScoped<ICarService, CarService>();
           }));

      Client = _server.CreateClient();
}
```

from tests I'm using this `HttpClient` to test my API.

```
using (var response = await _client.GetAsync($"/api/car/{id}"))
{
    //...         
}
```

The thing is that I want to fake the result of the `GetAsync(int id)` method in `CarService` class.

So I tried

```
var myCarObject = ... omitted for clarity
var myCarMockService = new Mock<ICarService>();
myCarMockService.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(myCarObject));
```

I don't know is this right approach, but if it is how can I inject it
into `Fixture` class so `CarService` can use it.

```
public class CarService: ICarService {
    private readonly CarDbContext _carDbContext;

    public CarService(CarDbContext carDbContext)
    {
        _carDbContext = carDbContext;
    }

    public async Task<Car> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _carDbContext.Cars.FindAsync(id);
    }
}
```

Update:

```
private readonly ICarService _carService;

public CarController(ICarService carService)
{
    _carService = carService;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] int id)
{
    var car = await _carService.GetAsync(id);
}
```

Update 2:

```
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddDbContext<CarDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db")); });
       services.AddTransient<ICarService, CarService>();
   }
}

public class CarService : ICarService
{
    private readonly CarDbContext _carDbContext;

    public ContactService(CarDbContext carDbContext)
    {
       _carDbContext= carDbContext;
    }
    public async Task<Owner> GetAsync(int ownerId)
    {
       var owner = await _carDbContext.Owners.FindAsync(ownerId);
       return owner.Car;            
    }
}
```

Update 3:

```
private readonly TestServer _server;
public Fixture()
{
    var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CarDbContext>()
                    .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                    .Options;

    var mockContext = new Mock<CarDbContext>(dbContextOptions);
    var mockOwnerSet = new Mock<DbSet<Owner>>();
    var mockCarSet = new Mock<DbSet<Car>>();
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Owners).Returns(mockOwnerSet.Object);
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Cars).Returns(mockCarSet.Object);          

    var carService = new CarService(mockContext.Object);

    _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, conf) =>
        {
            conf.AddJsonFile(@Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "../appsettings.json");
        }).UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddDbContext<CarDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Test"));
                services.AddScoped<ICarService>(_ => carService);
            })
        );

    Client = _server.CreateClient();    
}
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. Could you share `MyService` implementation as well?

Comment: You can mock HTTPClient

Comment: @Johnny, I updated the q with Service implementation

Comment: If you are using `HttpClient`to invoke the API that means you are hitting the actual service. If you don't have intention to hit the actual service, then you should write your unit test for `CarService` only.

Comment: @user1672994 I do have the intention to hit CarService I just want to fake result from its GetAsync method.

Comment: @user1765862 you could easily mock `ICarService` and inject it in the test context...

Comment: @Johnny, I have it mocked already, but I don't know how to inject it having my code 
 from question in mind.

Comment: You're missing the point. This is an integration test. It makes no sense to do what you're asking. If you want to test your service, use a unit test.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, are you suggesting that I should just mock ICarService? If you don't mind please post an answer with your suggestion. I want to make use of the integration test with using only HttpClient.GetAsync for testing my endpoint.

Comment: No. All you need for the purpose of your integration test is test data, so you should actually "mock" the context that the service uses. However, mocking `DbContext` is a pain in the arse, so it's preferable to simply use the in-memory provider, which you can sub in in your web host setup in the fixture.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, can you please check my updated question (latest -> update 3). I'm using mockedDbContext now and inMemoryDb in WebHostBuilder but I'm still getting null in await _carDbContext.Owners.FindAsync(ownerId); What I'm missing here?

Comment: Don't use a mocked context. The in-memory database is an alternative approach; you aren't supposed to do both. The problem with mocking the context is that there's so much that needs to be stubbed out: all the `DbSet`s, etc. The in-memory provider lets you use your actual context class, but with a fake connection, basically. Additionally, you'll need to seed the test data.

Answer (score 2):

Configure the test server to use the mocked service

```
public Fixture() {

    Car myCarObject = //... omitted for brevity
    var myCarMockService = new Mock<ICarService>();
    myCarMockService
        .Setup(x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(myCarObject);

    _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureTestServices(services => {
            var serviceDescriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(ICarService));
            if (serviceDescriptor != null) services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);
            services.AddTransient<ICarService>(_ => myCarMockService.Object); // <-- NOTE
        })
    );

    Client = _server.CreateClient();
}
```

That way when the call is made the mocked service will be injected as expected.

Comment: thanks for the effort, I was sure that this will work, but I'm still getting null from  return await _carDbContext.Cars.FindAsync(id);

Comment: No this example replaces the entire car service. it should be calling your actual implementation class. I assume ICarservice is being injected into a controller? the controller should be using the mocked ICarService

Comment: That's correct, my service is using DI, but still I'm getting null from _carDbContext.Cars.FindAsync(id). It looks like that I need to mock dbContext as well? (if so I'm completely confused :)

Comment: @user1765862 check updated answer. Note the `ConfigureTestServices`